# Is it possible to make an average of nested values in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am searching for a way to retrieve nested values and sum them. I know that it is possible to do it in MySQL with a join but it seems that it is harder to do in MongoDB. I wonder if it is even possible.

The thing that looks the most like what I want to do is `$graphLookup`. However when reading the doc it seems that it doesn't do exactly what I need.

Please consider the following collection:

```
{
  "question1": {
    "answer1": {
      "value": "yes",
      "count": 5
    },
    "answer2": {
      "value": "no",
      "count": 3
    }
  },
  "question2": {
    "answer1": {
      "value": "red",
      "count": 10
    },
    "answer2": {
      "value": "pink",
      "count": 7
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the total of all `count` fields in the collection?

Comment: Could you post your actual sample collection copying from mongoshell

Comment: Sorry I don't have an actual sample collection